# Use POST and GET in the same view django

Tags: javascript, python, django

On clicking a button (send_net), I want to send the text stored in the input "text" from a django template to a view and to the url associated with that view.

The associated html:

```
<div class="search_box">
<form id="target" action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" id = "sbox" placeholder="Search...">
  <a href = "create_network" type="button" id="send_net"></a>          
</form>
</div>
```

I send the variable to the view using a POST request:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
 $('#send_net').click(function(e){
  var query = document.getElementById("sbox").value;
  var d = {'query':query};
  $.ajax( link, {
    type: "POST",
    data: d,
    success: function(data) {
      alert('call back');
    },
    error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Error, status = " + textStatus + ", " +
          "error thrown: " + errorThrown
    );
    }
  });
});
```

});

views.py

```
def create_network(request):
    c={}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    r=[]
    if request.method=='POST':
        if 'query' in request.POST:
            query = request.POST['query']
            r.append({'id':1, 'label':query})
    venues = Venue.objects.filter(title__contains="Life")
    for venue in venues:
        d={}
        d['id'] = venue.id
        d['label'] = venue.title
        r.append(d)
    data = json.dumps(r)
    edges = [{'from':15505, 'to':19092}]
    data_e = json.dumps(edges)
    con = RequestContext(request, {"nodes":data, "edges":data_e})
    return render_to_response('quir/network.html', c, con)
```

However r never has the '{'id':1, 'label':query}' because the subsequent GET request wipes it clean. How do I retain the query value in 'r'? I'm relatively new to Django and javascript so sorry if this is elementary. 
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/) and define a method for GET and another one for POST:

```
class CreateNetwork(View):  # Extend from the view you need

    c = {}
    r = []

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # This code will be executen in a GET request

        # here you can access c or r with self
        self.c.update(csrf(request))  # this is just an example
        ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # This code will be executed in a POST request

        self.r.append(...)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I also stored the variable I got from the POST in request.sessions (for anyone's future reference)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   pass # Your code
else:
   pass # For GET
```

When you want to process both POST and GET, you need to specify it like so.